# File name/line number of the calling method/file without preprocessor

Tags: c++

I've got a logging method that shall show some additional information for logging console outputs:

Log.hpp:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline static constexpr void log(const ARGS&... args)
{
    std::cout << __FILE__ << "#" << __LINE__; // << args...
}
```

and the calling file A.cpp:

```
log("hello");
```

When the console message is shown the file name and line number are - of course - taken from the Log.hpp. But the intention is to know from where the log method was called.

Is there something EXCEPT preprocessor-defines that I can use to get the file name (A.cpp) and the line number from A.cpp? My coding style forbids preprocessor usage except for file inclusions/include guards.

Comment: With `inline static constexpr void log(const char line[] = __LINE__, const ARGS&... args)` it takes the "hello" parameter as the `line` input parameter ;)

Comment: Maybe you could consult changing the coding style with your co-workers? Macros have very bad opinion for a reason, but there are places (like this) where they make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify your code as follow:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline static constexpr void log(const char* fileName, int lineNumber,const ARGS&... args)
{
    std::cout << fileName << "#" << lineNumber; // << args...
}
```

Then:

```
log(__FILE__, __LINE__, "hello");
```

**Edit-1**:

Try with this too...

```
#define log(message) log(__FILE__, __LINE__, (message))
```

Comment: thanks but is it possible somehow else? This requires changes to the log call in in thousands of lines of core... so I would like to keep the interface the same

Comment: Please look at my "Edit-1".